# how do I add a label to all metrics collected by vmagent?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, victoriametrics

the task is to add the permanent label k8s_cluster=state to the help chart victoria-metrics-agent, I tried adding it via extraLabels, but it is added only to pod, deployment, etc. vmagent
I use helm chart https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/helm-charts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried configuring vmagent with the following flag:

```
/path/to/vmagent -remoteWrite.label=k8s_cluster=state ...
```

https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html#adding-labels-to-metrics